# Google Sheets arrayformula for 2D lookup with most recent matches

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

See this spreadsheet (feel free to make copies of the 'Attempt' sheet and have a go): https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PCaMLIyxC75QSYBg8qXrImAEIKmT3PMqzru_mJeGw8M/edit#gid=0

On the 'Input data' sheet is a list of building purchases, renovations and sales, with the year it happened, and the floor area of the floor afterwards.

What I want is on the 'Desired result' sheet... A table of years with a column for each building. The cell values are the floor areas for the given building in the given year. I want one formula in cell B3 that will complete the table and automatically update as the 'Input data' sheet is changed.

I have managed to make an arrayformula that in cell B3 that gives the desired values for that row, which can be copied down to give the desired values for all rows; however, what I want is one formula in cell B3 that does the whole table.

I have gotten very close with a couple of nested MMULT functions, but couldn't quite make it work. I'm guessing there's probably a tricky QUERY function, but I haven't got my head around the syntax of QUERY yet. I'm also interested if anyone can do it without QUERY.

Part of what makes it tricky is that the formula needs to find the most recent match up to the year in question (rather than finding an exact match).

Many thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've added a new sheet ("Erik Help") with the following formula:

`=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(B2:F2&A3:A,SORT({'Input data'!A2:A&'Input data'!B2:B,'Input data'!A2:A},1,1),2,TRUE)<>B2:F2,IF(A3:A="",,0),VLOOKUP(B2:F2&A3:A,SORT({'Input data'!A2:A&'Input data'!B2:B,'Input data'!C2:C},1,1),2,TRUE))))`

Key Concepts:

Whenever you want to fill a grid like this, you typically concatenate elements (as I have done with `&` here), in both the search-key elements and the search-range elements.

When you need to look up "data between data" (like years between years), you can use `VLOOKUP` with the final parameter set to `TRUE`, which means fall back to the last entry if there isn't an exact match." However, in order for TRUE to work, all of the search-range entries must be in strict ascending order, hence the `SORT` wraps you see. However, when `SORT`ed, some elements in your case may "fall back" to a year-company combination that isn't for that company; so the first `IF` clause makes sure that every "fall back" find matches by company. If not, null or 0 is returned (depending on whether Col A is occupied). If so, then the correct "fall back" result is returned.

Comment: Excellent, thanks Erik! The only thing that needed improving was exending the column range to pick up any additional buildings added to the Input data list. That is, B2:F2 references needed to be updated to B2:2. Then, so that the formula doesn't calculate for blank columns, I put an ARRAY_CONSTRAIN around it:

=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(B2:2&A3:A,SORT({'Input data'!A2:A&'Input data'!B2:B,'Input data'!A2:A},1,1),2,TRUE)<>B2:2,IF(A3:A="",,0),VLOOKUP(B2:2&A3:A,SORT({'Input data'!A2:A&'Input data'!B2:B,'Input data'!C2:C},1,1),2,TRUE)))),COUNTA(A3:A),COUNTA(B2:2))

Comment: I'm glad you were able to adapt it to your liking, Todd. I will say, however, that it isn't so much an "improvement" as a personal change. We can only write around what posters include in their posts. You included exactly and only up to Year 2022 and building E, without mention of need to expand on that. Beyond that, it is always up to the poster to adapt formulas found on forums (or to include further details). The important thing is you got it working in the end according to what was in your head.

Comment: On the contrary Erik, in the OP I said "I want one formula in cell B3 that will complete the table and *automatically update as the 'Input data' sheet is changed*."

Comment: Todd, I understand that for you, who knew inside your head what "changed" might mean, that apparently included adding more columns. That would not be what most would take from "when the 'Input Data' sheet is changed." That is, most would assume you meant "when data is changed," not "when structure is changed." That needs to be stated specifically. I will say, however, that you are now looking a gift horse in the mouth and fighting for, at best, some sort of pyrrhic victory here. The takeaway: the most specific a post is, the more likely the solution will fit "out of the box."

Comment: Okay Erik. I only added the original comment in case someone else looked at your great solution (which I already praised and thanked you for) and wanted to know how to make it work for any size input data table.